# Checkboxes and the "Other" field

Tags: google-forms

I've set up Google Forms to track initiatives across 41 locations. The form utilizes the Checkbox option in setup, which also allows me to utilize an OTHER field. I'm using it to collect anecdotal feedback on the form after staff have selected various check boxes.

However, lot of individuals overlook the OTHER field not realizing that it is where they can share text related to their experience. So I'd like to change it to "Feedback" or "How did it go?" instead of "OTHER".

Is it possible to change the text of "Other" in that field on the form?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't include an option bro customize the label for the "other" checkbox / radio button options.

One alternative is add an specfic question with the desired text.